# In AOSP what files to copy to target or what jar to copy on building in frameworks base

Tags: android, android-source

For example If I am modifying something in
frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java then how should I build only related package and copy to target than building complete AOSP image. I can't use "adb sync" since my build is in remote machine.

Even just knowing what to copy will help after building all, than copying whole image

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to figure out which files may have been indirectly affected by your change. `find /out/.../system -newer fileyouchanged.java` should *usually* work, I think.

But...

> I can't use "adb sync" since my build is in remote machine.

Use ssh forwarding to make `adb sync` (and adb in general) work over ssh.

From `man ssh_config`:

```
RemoteForward
             Specifies that a TCP port on the remote machine be forwarded over
             the secure channel. [...]
```

So, you'd put a `RemoteForward 5037 localhost:5037` line in your ssh config file (e.g. ~/.ssh/config), preferably only for that specific host.

Super convenient!

(if it sometimes doesn't work, make sure that `adbd` is running on your local machine through `adb start-server`, and that it isn't running on the remote with `adb kill-server`.)

Comment: I have connected to server over VPN. I can access server over ssh. But, I can't ping from my server to my PC. I guess since ping itself doesn't work from server to PC, port forward won't work

Comment: Yes, it will be transported over the ssh connection -- if ssh works, ssh RemoteForward will work.

Comment: Shouldn't ssh from server to my PC should work for this to work ? for me only ssh to server from my PC works

Comment: No, you only a single ssh session (from your PC to the server) for this to work. The data is transported over that ssh connection. sshd on the server will listen on the specified port locally, package any communication received on that part, and send it over your ssh connection. On your PC, ssh will connect to the forwarding-target port, and forward the received communication packets.